Asking for user input in a while loop in a bash script
I am running on Ubuntu 24.04.
I created a bash script that reads a file line by line in a loop and asks in this loop for a user input. (In fact it calls a function where this happens and something more, but to simplify my problem, we can ignore that)
Here is a simpel version of my script:
#!/bin/bash

REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST="./files_to_copy.txt"

while IFS=' ' read -r remote_file local_dest
do
        echo
        echo "Line = " "$remote_file" "$local_dest"
        read -p "Please enter your name: " name
        echo "Hello, $name!"
        echo

done < "$REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST"


I understand that the reason for a failure of that script is the fact that the first read is not finished while I start the 2nd read. What are my options here ?
Thanks in advance and best regards
Daniel
Actual result:
Line =  /home/azureconf/conf/ubuntu/05-sentinelconnector.conf /etc/rsyslog.d
Hello, /home/azureconf/conf/ubuntu/rsyslog.conf /etc!
Expected result:
Line =  /home/azureconf/conf/ubuntu/05-sentinelconnector.conf /etc/rsyslog.d
Please enter your name: Daniel
Hello, Daniel
Line =  /home/azureconf/conf/ubuntu/rsyslog.conf /etc
Please enter your name: Daniel
Hello, Daniel

You should open a dedicated fifo! Have a look here: How to deal with stream input in bash: some recommendations.

See BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?).

Use a dedicated file descriptor:
Under bash, you could generate temporary unnamed fifo, then link them do a free file descriptor and store his value into a variable by simply: {varname}<  syntax:
#!/bin/bash

REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST="./files_to_copy.txt"

while IFS=' ' read -ru $CONFIG remote_file local_dest; do
    echo
    echo "Line = " "$remote_file" "$local_dest"
    read -p "Please enter your name: " name
    echo "Hello, $name!"
    echo
done  {CONFIG}< "$REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST"


Some other samples: How to 'grep' a continuous stream?, and Read a file line by line and execute commands: 4+ answers at paragraph 4.2.

You can do this in other (non-bash) shells (and pre-4.0 versions of bash (cough macOS cough)) using a fixed extra FD like #3: while IFS=' ' read -r remote_file local_dest <&3; do ... done  3< "$REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST". The only problem with the fixed FD is if that same FD is also used for something else and that other usage is needed inside the loop you'll get a conflict. (But note that read -p is also a bashism.)

@GordonDavisson You're right, but as question is tagged bash...I will maybe post a POSIX version later...

Another approach would be to preload the file.
That's not a great idea if it's very big, but if you are prompting the user on every line I assume it isn't millions or even hundreds of lines, so this approach should be simple and workable.
REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST="./files_to_copy.txt"
mapfile -t list < "$REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST" # load the whole file to an array
for line in "${list[@]}"               # loop over the array
do  remote_file="${line% *}"           # parse out the first field
    local_dest="${line#* }"            # parse out the second field
    echo "Line = $remote_file $local_dest"
    read -p "Please enter your name: " name
    printf "Hello, %s!\n\n" "$name"
done

This smacks strongly of an X/Y Problem, though.
You might get better answers if you explain what you are trying to accomplish.

SO asker approach seem not as complex? There is simply two different input, so having two file descriptor seem logical. Having to preload whole list is not more intuitive and not simpler.Knowing how to manipulate many different input sources is a good thing! See How to 'grep' a continuous stream?

File descriptor solutions had already been provided. I just offered an alternative for folk who might prefer it - mostly a thought experiment. "Simpler" is largely a matter of taste.

I agree, but I don't this match definition of an XY problem.

Since you asked for options - if the file or dest are unique then you could always read the file into an associative array first then loop on its contents, e.g. untested
#!/usr/bin/env bash

REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST="./files_to_copy.txt"

declare -A file2dest
while IFS=' ' read -r remote_file local_dest; do
        file2dest["$remote_file"]="$local_dest"
done < "$REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST"

for remote_file in "${!file2dest[@]}"; do
        local_dest="${file2dest[$remote_file]}"
        echo
        echo "Line = " "$remote_file" "$local_dest"
        read -p "Please enter your name: " name
        echo "Hello, $name!"
        echo
done

Use whichever value is unique as the array index.
If neither are unique then you could do the same with an indexed array:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST="./files_to_copy.txt"

declare -a file_dest
while IFS= read -r line; do
        file_dest+=( "$line" )
done < "$REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST"

for line in "${file_dest[@]}"; do
        remote_file="${line% *}"
        local_dest="${line#* }"
        echo
        echo "Line = " "$remote_file" "$local_dest"
        read -p "Please enter your name: " name
        echo "Hello, $name!"
        echo
done


Thank you Ed, as Hauris answer worked like a charme for me, I will just save your ideas in my notepad for future reference :)
So your time is not wasted and you helped me to improve my shell scripting (which I started today btw.)

You're welcome. Since you're just starting - for future scripts make sure to copy/paste your code into http:shellcheck.net and fix any issues it tells you about and read correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization to learn when [not] to use all-capitals in variable names.

Also, in case you're actually writing a loop to manipulate text, see why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice - that's an extremely common mistake beginners make.

@EdMorton Using one field as index key implie there is only one local_dest for any remote_file. There is no reason to limit this!

@DanielGoernert Paul Hodges's answer should work too, with near same approach and without the limitation about index keys.

a little less typing: mapfile -t file_dest < "${REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST}"

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub please read what I said about that in my answer.

@markp-fuso yeah I realised that as soon as I posted it but by then PaulHodges had posted his answer using that and so I didn't want to duplicate that in my answer.

There is absolutely no need for any bashism here. A plain POSIX grammar code is even clearer to read:
#!/bin/sh

REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST="./files_to_copy.txt"

while IFS=' ' read -r remote_file local_dest || [ "$local_dest" ]; do
    printf '\nLine = "%s" "%s"\n' "$remote_file" "$local_dest"
    printf 'Please enter your name: '
    read -r name <&1 # Reads from stdin
    printf 'Hello, %s!\n' "$name"
    printf \\n
done < "$REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST" # Reads from file

Checking if running in a terminal as required for input while allowing output redirection as suggested by @GordonDavisson
#!/bin/sh

if ! [ -t 0 ]; then
  printf 'This script needs a terminal!\n' >&2
  exit 1
fi

REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST="./files_to_copy.txt"

while IFS=' ' read -r remote_file local_dest || [ "$local_dest" ]; do
  printf '\nLine = "%s" "%s"\n' "$remote_file" "$local_dest"
  printf 'Please enter your name: ' > /dev/tty # Output to terminal
  read -r name < /dev/tty # Input from terminal
  printf 'Hello, %s!\n' "$name"
  printf \\n
done <"$REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST" # Reads from file


<&1 actually reads from stdout, so this won't work if the script's output is redirected someplace other than the terminal.

@GordonDavisson I'd be curious to know how you think it should be done to still keep the terminal input when redirecting the output. Sure it could test the availability of an interactive terminal and read from < /dev/tty. Was it what you expected?

That's one possibility. You could also copy the original stdin to another FD (e.g. ... done 3<&0 <"$REMOTE_CONFIG_LIST" and redirect the interactive read from that. But what I generally prefer to do in situations like this is put the file being read on another FD, and make the read at the top of the loop read from that (see F. Hauri's answer and my comment on it).
